# statsmodels - very small p values always rounded to zero

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am performing a binomial logistic regression in statsmodels and p-values are always rounded to 0 instead of being written out in scientific notation.

Other model result parameters, such as the standard error are written in scientific notation.

I have checked both the `model.summary()` (`P>|z|` column) output and `model.pvalues` but value is always 0.

Is there a way to prevent this rounding off in p values and obtain the actual value ?

This is statsmodels version 0.9.0 on Python 3.7

### Edit 1

The output of `getcontext()` from `Decimal` is :

```
Context(prec=28, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN, Emin=-999999, Emax=999999,         capitals=1, clamp=0, flags=[FloatOperation], traps=[Overflow, ivisionByZero, InvalidOperation])
```

but `Decimal(pvalue)` returns 0.

Comment: try giving a precision value using decimal

Comment: I think I tried that - I've just edited the question with the output.

Comment: Just inspect the pvalues directly through `model.pvalues`.

Comment: `model.pvalues` is floating point precision and not rounded. If it is really 0.0, then most likely you have a strange edge case. In Logit, precision of the estimate is limited by the default convergence criterion which might be only around 1e-6 for the parameter estimates.